# Reordering matrix variables with subscripts

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, sorting

I want to calculate a matrix product that preserves the ordering of variables as `x` then `a` then `y`. However this doesn't work if there are subscripts:

```
CPOrdering[x] = 1;
CPOrdering[a] = 2;
CPOrdering[y] = 3;

xx = {{Subscript[x, 1, 1], Subscript[x, 1, 2]},
    {Subscript[x, 2, 1], Subscript[x, 2, 2]}};

aa = {{Subscript[a, 1, 1], Subscript[a, 1, 2]},
    {Subscript[a, 2, 1], Subscript[a, 2, 2]}};

yy = {{Subscript[y, 1, 1], Subscript[y, 1, 2]},
    {Subscript[y, 2, 1], Subscript[y, 2, 2]}};

xx.aa.yy
```

The ordering is `a`, `x`, `y`. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: for purpose of formatting or do you want to have non commutative multiplication?

Comment: formatting purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Fold[Inner[Inactive[Times], ##] &, {xx, aa, yy}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: This looks nice. If there are some zero matrix elements in `xx`, `aa`, `yy` (e.g. if we set `Subscript[a, 1, 2]=0`), is it possible to not print any zero values?

Comment: @MedullaOblongata add `/. (0 -> "")` or something